# How to invoke a method after getting the HTTP Session In Angular 6

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, angular6

I want to use `json` data from `back-end` in `front-end`. And the json data will come if the user has `Session` so I want to invoke the `getReoprts()` method on service class to be called after getting the `HTTP session`. How to do it in `Angular 6`.
Here is the snippet.

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PdcReportsService implements OnInit {
  baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  getQuickLinkGroups() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/quickLinkGroups.action`, {
    });
  }
  getReports() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/reports.action`, {
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getReports();
  }
}
```

Thanks In Advance..

Comment: you have to subscribe to `this.getReports()` in order to the http request to be fired. Inside the subscription you can execute your logic.

Comment: Furthermore OnInit is for component only not service. It won't be triggered at all.